# Should I use rememberCoroutineScope or viewModelScope? Which one is right for my scenario?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In my example, I need to perform a process and if it is successful, the app should navigate to the next page.

The first approach uses viewmodel scope on a non suspend function and then uses a callback to let the UI know that the process is complete. The second approach is declaring a coroutine scope in the UI level and then making the viewmodel a suspend function.

Which would be the right approach for my scenario?
What's the advantage of each approach over the other?
Is there a particular scenario where one approach is more applicable than the other?

**First approach:**

UI:

```
    Button(
        onClick = { 
            vm.process(
                onSuccess = { navcontroller.Navigate("nextpage") }, 
                onFail = { errorMessage.value = it }
            ) 
        }
    )
```

ViewModel:

```
fun process() {
    viewmodelScope.launch {
        val err = process()
        if(err.isBlank()) {
          onSuccess()
        } else {
          onFail(err)
        }    
    }
}
```

**Second approach?**

UI:

```
   val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
   Button(onClick = {
       scope.launch {
          val err = vm.process()
          if(err.isBlank()) {
              navController.navigate("nextPage")
          } else {
              errorMessage.value = err
          }
       }
   })
```

ViewModel:

```
    suspend fun process() : String {
        val err = process()
        if(err.isBlank()) {
          onSuccess()
        } else {
          onFail(err)
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Qs:** What's the difference between `rememberCoroutineScope()` & `viewmodelscope`?

The `rememberCoroutineScope()` is tied to the lifecycle of the composable & the `ViewModelScope` is the same as the lifecycle scope, the only difference is that the coroutine in this scope will live as long as the view model is alive.

**i.e**
On orientation change, the coroutines in `ViewModelScope` will live but the `lifecycle` scope's coroutines will die/end.